# Learning at work

Tags: developer, software-development, learning

In IT business, is it common for companies (managers) to allow employees to allocate working hours for learning new tools, frameworks etc?

As I am a junior/mid-level front-end engineer, spending 10 percent of the week working hours learning something new would not only allow me to improve as a developer, but also increase productivity due to expanded knowledge. Still, is it an accepted practice?

Comment: A previous manager of mine asked if anyone knew C++.  I said I took C in school.  He put the book on my desk and said I was our new C++ expert.  So..... yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every company is different so you'd need to ask your manager.  I wouldn't ask in the same way you have here.  Perhaps a short email stating that when you have down time, would it be acceptable to research (A..B..C) and that way, if your internet history is recorded, you can show that your manager said it was okay (if they do).

That's how it works for me.  I get training but if I find myself at a loose end, it's perfectly fine if I jump on Google for a bit of research but I did ask my manager before doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I think company like us ( Since we are in R&D business and I'm a driver developer), have allocated more than 10% for R&D things and learning. In our case we don't have limitations in internet access and learning.

We also have a program that give credits so motivate our employees for new ideas and patents.

So it depends, no matter it's web development, there are many R&D areas. So depends on the working filed and the company you work.

Answer (score 2):

Each company might have a different attitude to this.

Generally you are expected to know the core of your profession and be able to learn on the job anything you need. It's less likely that they will allocate you unsupervised hours to learn things you feel like learning.

However it's fairly common to give you time for study if it is a pre-approved course you're taking which is in line with their protocols. Some companies will even pay course and exam fees.

Comment: A proper framework take month to master enough for a proper use in a production environment, having some proper formation outside of any project is really better. Learning huge things like this while developping a project is just a huge call to our dear Murphy.